# Ошибка при подключении модели

Tags: php, ооп, codeigniter

Пытаюсь подключить модель в контроллере

```
<?php
class Poc extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('poc_model');
```

Сама модель лежит по обычному пути в папке models

```
models/Poc_model.php
```

Код в модели выглядит следующим образом:

```
<?php
class Poc_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function getAllFields(){
        return $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('status' => 1))->result_array();
    }
}
```

Создал метод в контроллере

```
public function addAncetData() {
    $allFields = $this->Poc->getAllFields();
    print_r($allFields);
```

при обращении к которому выходит ошибка:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Poc::$Poc
>
> Filename: controllers/Poc.php

Что делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас:

```
$allFields = $this->Poc->getAllFields();
```

А надо:

```
$allFields = $this->poc_model->getAllFields();
```